# How to serialize a chart from Chart.js into a JSON to re create it later

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, charts, chart.js

I'm trying to serialize a Chart from Chart.js into a JSON in order to save it into a database and de-serialize it later to render it again, but I'm stuck.

If I try to use JSON.stringify on the chart object or with the result of .getDatasetMeta(), I can't because I have circular structure and the method can't convert it (Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON).

I developed an interface to make the user able to custom his Chart the way he wants and so I'm only interested by saving important data that the user would have set( data itself, labels, colors, beginAtZero, fill ... )

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: if the properties you want to save are named and known before, you can write a function that extracts them from the object and set it to a new js object that you will JSON encode. Then you need to write the inverse function, that sets back the properties from decoded saved object

Comment: Yep that was my idea but I wanted to know if there a simpler way because  the properties are different for each type of graph so I would have to create  different functions for each one :/

Comment: i know no internal function that does this, if it exists i'd like to know.. libraries should exist for this, but if you don't want to use one, you can write a generic function that extracts properties from an array of property names. Each type of graph can have its preset array for extraction.

Comment: I ended up doing it this way, thank you.